# Is there Roslyn or FodyWeaver function for replacing inheritance chain to one class?

Tags: c#, .net, roslyn

COM Objects don't allow uses inheritance.
I have many classes with devided logic, for re-use code.
Can Roslyn change class inheritance and combine classes together?
Or any fody weavers?
How overwhelmed is using Roslyn for this task?

Example:

```
    public class BaseFunc
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public decimal X { get; set; }
        public decimal Y { get; set; }

        public decimal Sum()
        {
            return X + Y;
        }
    }

    public class ConsoleFunc : BaseFunc
    {
        public void WriteLine()
        {
            Console.WriteLine($@"X + Y = {Sum()}");
        }
    }

    public class ConsolasFuncComObject : ConsoleFunc
    {
        public void Init()
        {
        }
    }
```

As result I want to get this code or compiled code

```
    public class ConsolasFuncComObjectFull
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public decimal X { get; set; }
        public decimal Y { get; set; }

        public decimal Sum()
        {
            return X + Y;
        }
        public void WriteLine()
        {
            Console.WriteLine($@"X + Y = {Sum()}");
        }
        public void Init()
        {
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can 'combine' your inheritance into one class with [Mono.Cecil](https://www.mono-project.com/docs/tools+libraries/libraries/Mono.Cecil/) or [dnLib](https://github.com/0xd4d/dnlib)

Shouldn't be too hard. Course of action:

1. Collect all of the classes you need to "crush down"
2. Do a `foreach` through all classes resolving all inheritance tree
3. Remove inheritance from each class
4. Add/remove wanted fields/properties/methods into it
5. Save your assembly.